# Tumblr isn't accepting my theme because of non-http urls

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-html

I changed all http into https but this continues to pop up:
"Uh oh! We couldn't save your theme. Looks like your custom theme references assets from non-HTTPS URLs. Please try again using only HTTPS URLs."

Link to my theme code: pastebin(.)com/raw/0Rr9nHcy

Comment: I too am experiencing this issue for the first time. For me, I was simply changing the "bio" field of my theme to change a bit of text to link to a URL (of a specific post on the same Tumblr site I'm trying to edit). First obvious thought is to skim through my custom bio html snippet and ensure all 'http' instances are instead 'https'; but to my surprise it's throwing up the same error when I go to save the changes. Which leads me to believe the changes I'm making to the bio are not the issue. Instead, in my limited view, it seems like the error would have come up regardless if no changes were

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this same issue on Tumblr.  Here's how to resolve it.

1. Go to Edit Theme > Edit HTML.  Go through all of your html and change any links to files (css/javascript etc.) from http to https - this should only links in src attributes, you shouldn't have to change any href attributes.  Once you've finished Update Preview and then Save.

If you get the error "Uh oh! We couldn't save your theme. Looks like your custom theme references assets from non-HTTPS URLs. Please try again using only HTTPS URLs." when you save do the following:

1. Copy all of your theme out to a plain text editor such as textedit.  Exit Edit HTML and go back to the Main Edit Appearance screen.  Refresh your browser and go back into Edit Theme > Edit HTML.  Delete all your theme's html and copy your saved html back into Tumblr's Edit HTML.  Now it should save.

Disclaimer: I am not responsible if you delete your theme's HTML without having saved it somewhere first - please follow the instructions carefully!

Comment: Good advice. I sometimes empty the html entire then save it. As it either caches changes or they don't get updated in the DB straight away.

Comment: Ahhh no, this is a friggin nightmare. I just had to update my theme and it contains loads of links to my own site, which is still http. But regardless of that any number of themes could have links to http assets (images, fonts, javascript and so on).

Comment: @lharby I think it's the way Tumblr's edit interface works (or is failing to).  When you save changes within edit there is no page refresh so I'm guessing the asynchronous javascript is a little buggy.  Https is completely unnecessary for the front end of Tumblr and if you have looked at any of Tumblr recently using any type of adblocker extension you'll seem many of the sites don't work any more.  Tumblr seems determined recently to kill off their userbase - oh well.

Comment: @lharby oh remember "only links in src attributes, you shouldn't have to change any href attributes" - so normal links to your site should be fine, you don't have to change them.  It's only resources that are being loaded i.e. css, javascript etc.

Comment: Thanks, most of it actually is going to be migrated to https (I have an icon css file loaded over https, but I can resolve that I think). So I hope this is doable. Thank you for the update.